# Taking screenshots 16.04

Tags: screenshot

I'm not having trouble taking the screen shots. When I use **alt and prtsc** I am given the option of where to save it at. However, when I use **ctrl alt prtsc** to take a screen shot of a certain section, the window acts like it's going to come up, but then goes away.. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to take screenshot of whole windows press `PrntScr` or `Altr + PrntScr`.

But If You want to take screenshot of a certain section press `Shift + PrntScr`.